# How to inherit all event handlers from a custom object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, events, inheritance, event-handling, prototype

My JavaScript application is based on prototypal inheritance. Consider a chain of constructors, whereas a new instance of a higher member is used as a prototype of a lower member. By that, properties get inherited across the whole chain.

Now, I would like to extend this by an event handling system that works similarly. Event handlers should be inherited from the top to the bottom.

```
function Parent() {};
Parent.prototype = new function() {
    this.foo = "bar";
}

function Child() {};
Child.prototype = new Parent();
with(Child.prototype) {
    qax = "foobar";
}
```

Firing an event by an instance of Child() should also call (inherit) the event handlers from Parent(). Parent() however, should only call its own event handlers since there is no higher object.

I would greatly appreciate if someone has an idea how this could be done (preferably using jQuery).

Comment: Are you sure you want inheritance, instead of a simple `tree` structure with instances of the same `node` type?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has nothing to with JS inheritance, though you might use some [`Callbacks`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Callbacks/) objects for organising your callbacks.

You could do something like

```
Parent.prototype.fire = function(args) {
    if (this.hasOwnProperty("callbacks")) {
         for (var i=0; i<this.callbacks.length; i++)
             this.callbacks[i].call(null, args);
    }
    var proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(this);
    if (proto && "fire" in proto)
        proto.fire(args);
};
```

Now, everything that inherits from `Parent.prototype` can use this method which checks for a "callback" array on the current instance, executes them and then recursively walks up the prototype chain until there is no `fire` method.

```
function Child() {
    this.callbacks = [console.log.bind(console, "Child level:")];
}
Child.prototype = new Parent;

function GrandChild() {
    this.callbacks = [console.log.bind(console, "GrandChild level:")];
}
GrandChild.prototype = new Child;

var gc = new GrandChild;
gc.fire("something");
```

However, I usually recommend not to use `new` for creating inheritance chains. Depending on your application structure, it might work, but know what you are doing. You could easily get lost in inheritance of nested objects, and also you might need to avoid creating local variables in your constructors.